# How to setup onclicklisteners in reused recyclerview adapters in the same activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am making a fitness app where the user puts in the number of reps he/she did and the weight used. I am using a recyclerview to make clickable data entry. I can use the same adapter to display both reps and weight but how to differentiate whether the reps recyclerview item was selected or the weight recyclerview item was selected. Currently I am using separate adapters for both weight and reps with a difference of only the onclicklistener.
Here are the reps and weight recyclerviews
[image: The reps and weight recyclerviews]

Here is the code for the reps adapter. The weight adapter is the same except for the listener

```
public class RepsReelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RepsReelAdapter.recyclerViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context ctx;
List<NumReel> data = Collections.emptyList();
private RepsClickListener repsClickListener;

public RepsReelAdapter(Context context, List<NumReel> data){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.ctx = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public recyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_row, parent, false);
    return new recyclerViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(recyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    NumReel current = data.get(position);
    holder.number.setText(String.valueOf(current.num));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class recyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView number;

    public recyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        number = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rnumber_tv);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(repsClickListener!=null){
            repsClickListener.repsClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}

public interface RepsClickListener{
    void repsClick(View view, int position);
}

public void setRepsClickListener (RepsClickListener repsListener){
    this.repsClickListener = repsListener;
}
```

Here is the implementation of the click in the activity

```
    @Override
public void repsClick(View view, int position) {
    reps_num = repsReelAdapter.data.get(position).num;
}
```

Comment: Yes what you are doing currently is OK, you will have to maintain 2 adapters, or you can put a switch statement in the onClick method, and tag each view being clicked with the data required to differentiate between the 2 different sets

Comment: I see your setting the click listener in ViewHolder itself, why not set it in the onBindViewHolder when you actually have the data

Comment: Is there an advantage of setting up OnClicklistener in onBindViewHolder compared to viewHolder?

Comment: yes you get access to the data being bound to the view

Comment: or you can just let the onclicklistener sit inside the viewholder just settag to the view with data by holding reference to the view in the viewholder

Comment: To set onClickListener in the viewholder, I would have to send NumReel to the ViewHolder and then setTag. It would be quite messy. Instead access to data is available in onBindViewHolder. Hence, setting up tag like you showed is much easier. Hence, when adapter is reused, the onclicklistener should be set in the onBindViewHolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the onClickListener in the viewholder set in onBindViewHolder like so,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(recyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    NumReel current = data.get(position);
    holder.number.setText(String.valueOf(current.num));
    holder.mView.setTag(current);
    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NumReel dataAttachedToThisView = (NumReel) v.getTag();
            // look at dataAttachedToThisView and decide if its weight or rep, then invoke
            // respective methods
        }
    });
}

class recyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView number;
    View mView;

    public recyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        number = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rnumber_tv);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(repsClickListener!=null){
            repsClickListener.repsClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

each adapter can hold a list of same data type, so you have to use the same class model that supplies the view with objects. What you can do is add an additional paramter called type or use inheritence

Comment: So you are suggesting that I pass a piece of information with NumReel that differentiates between weight and reps. Check for this differentiation onClick and then do the needful

Comment: @suku yes, each adapter can hold a list of same data type, so you have to use the same class model that supplies the view with objects. What you can do is add an additional paramter called type or use inheritence

Comment: Thanks, Bhargav. Can you add this to the answer you have given? It will be easier for others to understand